# VB.NET Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: vb.net, encryption, aes

I looked at other answers but I am still confused.

I am testing my encryption code that I copied in my ASP.NET project. I am not sure why it's having errors in vb.net. help!

Thanks in advance

```
  Dim EncryptionKey As String = "SamplePassword"

    Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() { 8 bytes here}, 10000)
    Using fileCrypt As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\output.txt", FileMode.Create)
        Using encrypt As New AesManaged()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(fileCrypt, encrypt.CreateDecryptor(pdb.GetBytes(32), pdb.GetBytes(16)), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Using fileInput As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\input.txt", FileMode.Open)
                    encrypt.KeySize = 256
                    encrypt.BlockSize = 128
                    Dim data As Integer
                    While (InlineAssignHelper(data, fileInput.ReadByte())) <> -1
                        cs.WriteByte(CByte(data))

                    End While
                End Using

            End Using
        End Using

    End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
  Dim plaintext as String
  Dim EncryptionKey As String = "SamplePassword"
  Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() { 8 bytes here}, 10000)

  Using encrypt As New AesManaged
        encrypt.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encrypt.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)

        ' Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform. 
        Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = encrypt.CreateDecryptor(encrypt.Key, encrypt.IV)

        ' Create the streams used for decryption. 
        Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Application.StartupPath + "\input.txt"))
            Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt)
                    ' Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                    ' and place them in a string.
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
                End Using 
            End Using 
        End Using 
    End Using
```

Comment: can't seem to use your answer. I'm using the other streams for encryption

Comment: Changed answer. Not sure is this work for you or not.